# Above 7mb Glue crawler is not creating table and skipping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

As I'm working on crawler and identify that above 2mb the crawler is not creating the schema and skipping the folder. Giving unknow as a file type.

As I can verify that below 2mb its creating the schema structure and proper file type in data catalog.

How to resolve this issues and any workaround for it?

Comment: This looks like issue in parsing your file. What is the file type? Are there any non utf-8 characters in it? If yes it will not as Glue can only parse UTF-8 characters. Upload your file to any repo and share it here if you need validation

Comment: we had a jsonl format file. I have transformed the job in glue and stored in csv fromat. It created different folder as it contain array and structs data types. Once i run the crawler on larger file. It's creating an empty schema and unknown file type in data catalog

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload the file to some repo and share it here? Unless looking at file it will not be possible to find the reason